# quanteda: subsetting the corpus based on key terms in title column

Tags: r, subset, corpus, quanteda

I have a corpus of approx. 8,000 news articles related to migration, migrants, asylum, and refugees. However, I would like to subset this corpus to articles that only include these terms in the title, because it appears that some of the articles mention migration but are not focused on migration. Any advice on how to do this, especially since naturally each title will include terms other than our key terms? Many thanks!

```
library(quanteda)
library(stringr)

text_corp <- quanteda::corpus(lemma_data_2008, 
                             text_field="Texte")
```

I tried the following (I have 4 key terms linked to migrants and refugees, also I hope to capture plurals)

```
corpus_subset(text_corp, str_detect(titre, fixed(c("migrant", "réfugié", "asile", "migratoire"), ignore_case = TRUE)))
```

however, the object "titre" could not be found (titre is title in French), though it exists as a column before I converted to a corpus.

Then I will proceed to the following:

```
dfm1 <- dfm(text_corp, remove_punct = TRUE, 
            remove_numbers = TRUE, 
            remove_symbol = TRUE, 
            remove = c(stopwords("french"), stop), dfm_remove = TRUE) %>% 
            dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 0.9, 
                termfreq_type = "quantile", 
                max_docfreq = 0.1, docfreq_type = "prop")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reproducible example here or more exact specification of your desired result, but I think I can guess it, so here goes.

You can use `corpus_subset()` for this combined with a logical condition to detect the terms in your title.  In the example below, we are looking for "two" in the title, regardless of its case (upper, lower, title case, etc.).

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.1.0

corp <- corpus(c("Text A", "Text B", "Text C", "Text D"),
  docvars = data.frame(title = c(
    "One two three",
    "four five",
    "Two six",
    "Seven eight"
  ))
)
corp
## Corpus consisting of 4 documents and 1 docvar.
## text1 :
## "Text A"
## 
## text2 :
## "Text B"
## 
## text3 :
## "Text C"
## 
## text4 :
## "Text D"

library("stringr")
corpus_subset(corp, str_detect(title, fixed("two", ignore_case = TRUE)))
## Corpus consisting of 2 documents and 1 docvar.
## text1 :
## "Text A"
## 
## text3 :
## "Text C"
```

Note: There are other ways to match the strings to your title (besides `stringr::str_detect()`), such as similar functions in **stringi**, or `base::grepl()`.  Take your pick.

Comment: Thank you so much! I put some of my code above, particularly as I would like to filter to multiple keywords in the title.